# Possible to open a page and issue a subsequent GET request with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get

I'm a penetration tester and I have just found, on a website we are testing, a flaw whereby the url of a video being embedded isn't checked, so I can embed offsite content. The problem is, however, first the page itself is called, then the embedded video is called in a second request. As such, this can't be sent in a single link to a would be victim, so the consequences of this flaw are currently very minor. There are XSS issues across the site though, so I was wondering if it were possible to inject some JavaScript which did this for me, i.e. first called the page and then called my offsite video.

I'd use window.location to open up the first page, but then how would I go about issuing the GET request to call the video?

I found some sample code and adapted it and have been trying to get it to work locally, but with no luck so far.

```
<script>
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

window.location = "http://www.thesite.com/vulnerablepage.htm";
httpGet("http://www.moviesite.com/embeddedvid.swf");
</script>
```

Would this, or something similar to it work? The website is live, so I can't really do any experimenting on it, otherwise I would have just used trial and error to find something that worked. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `return xmlHttp.responseText;` how do you expect this to harm the  victim site ? (and keep in mind that xhr will most probably get aborted , because browser is navigating away from the page that called this xhr)

Comment: My apologies for the error, in all honesty I just tried the original code with an intercepting proxy and saw it was making the get request, so I assumed it was what I needed. I see now returning the response data as a string is not needed! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A script (a malicious script planted via XSS attack) could create an `<iframe>` element, fetch your page into it, and then start the video.  So long as the page in the frame and the outer page where the attack payload (the script) is triggered are both in the same domain, it's possible (and quite easy really).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When calling the iframe however, would I not need some further JS to edit what video is called? As I want to replace the legitimate video with my offsite one.

Comment: The malicious JavaScript code running in the outer (containing) page will have full access to the contents of the `<iframe>` when it loads.  That includes the ability to modify the video setup, etc.